# BGTaskScheduler.shared.register Not Working Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "com.fetch.background", using: nil) { task in

            self.handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)

           }

          return true
      }
    func scheduleAppRefresh() {
       let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "com.fetch.background")
       // Fetch no earlier than 15 minutes from now.
       request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 15 * 60)
            
       do {
          try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
       } catch {
          print("Could not schedule app refresh: \(error)")
       }
    }

    
    func handleAppRefresh(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
       // Schedule a new refresh task.
       scheduleAppRefresh()

        
        print("this background fetch called")

     }
```

Above Code BGTaskScheduler completion Not working in swift 5, I added identifier with info.plist file permission. I need to use API with app background state. Please assist how can I achieve this one. Thanks

[image]

Comment: "Not working" is not a very helpful problem description.  Please read [ask]. What errors do you get? What behaviour do you get? Which version of Swift 5 are you using? Why do you think the problem is caused by Swift 5. Has the code ever worked?

Comment: Have you enabled background capabilities? Background fetch and background processing?

Comment: Did you solve this.  It doesn't work for me either.  The completion handler (closure) is never executed.